# SSL for subdomain

Tags: security, ssl-certificate, wildcards, subdomain, private-key

Can anyone please tell me, we have an SSL certificate for *.example.com but now we need separate SSL certificate for abc.example.com only for one subdomain. Is it possible? *.example.com which is wildcard.. So the original wildcard would be revoked if we purchased wildcard for subdomain? we want to host our career page to third party like (jobdiva) and they are asking for Intermediate CA, Private Key, Security certificate but I don't want to share my SSL of *.example.com thats'why I want an SSL for Subdomin. One more thing Can someone guide me how to get free SSL certificate for subdomain?

that would be great help

Comment: I expect that you can have certificates issued from different intermediate authorities without conflict (unless clients use certificate pinning for your domains). LetsEncrypt provides instructions on getting a free certificate: https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/

Answer (score 2):

Getting an SSL certificate for a specific subdomain wouldn't revoke an instance of a wildcard certificate for your domain. It would need to be a separate certificate though. (Same provider if you like, but separate certificate nonetheless)

The usual place now to get a free certificate is LetsEncrypt. There are many guides and tools to help you get a free certificate. Just treat your subdomain as being a "domain" and all will work just fine. The number of dots in a domain name isn't relevant to it being a domain name or subdomain name; the label simply implies ownership. Best in mind that LE certificates expect to be renewed monthly, and expire after three months unless renewed.

If your provider supports the use of LE certificates it should be very straightforward to get one allocated to your subdomain. (If they don't, ask them why not!)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, much appreciated. But I am little bit confused that I want to host my career page to a third party website that is jobdiva so in my case jobdiva would be subdomain?

Comment: You said you wanted abc.example.com to be the subdomain, given example.com as your main domain (and *.example.com as the wildcard ssl certificate)

Comment: Reissuance of Certificate would be helpful?

Comment: What about reissuing a certificate? Your wildcard certificate? If so, why would you want to do that?

Comment: Someone told me that , the best solution would be to reissue the wildcard certificate with a CSR generated on the third party's server, and then provide them with the SSL certificate files generated from the newer CSR.

Comment: If you want to do that, fine, but it won't solve the problem of you not providing them with the private key for your wildcard certificate

Comment: I would not recommend getting a wildcard certificate for a third-party-hosted subdomain (unless that third party is hosting all/most of your domain's content). If they're just hosting a single subdomain, get a certificate for that one subdomain.

Comment: @GordonDavisson exactly

Comment: Thank you for all your help but the problem is we are getting third party services from jobdiva portal and when we try to link their page with our website it takes a sweet time to load that page and we discuss that problem with that third-party vendor they said they optimize that link if we share the private key and Digital signature etc but due to security concerns we don't want to share that wildcard certificate with third-party thatswhy we thought to create a subdomain's SSL certificate and share it with them

Comment: Can you please guide me on how to install an SSL certificate for the subdomain by using LetsEnrypt, I am a newbie in this field your help would be highly helpful in this issue.

Comment: Just treat your subdomain as being a "domain" and all will work just fine.